# Skip every 100th number in Row_Number fucntion in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment, row-number

I have to make a auto increment sequence but it need to skip every 100th number and go to next number.

Example:

1,
2,
3,
... 99,101,102...199,201,202

Could anyone help on this

I tried rownum() over (partition by column_name)+1. But it is updating all row by 1 .

| previous_value | After_update |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 99 | 100 |

But I want to skip the assignment of 100th row number and go to 101 similarly 200th row number and go to 201

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problem necessitates skipping 100s as a solution? I've heard of triskaidekaphobia before, but fear of the number 100 is a new one to me.

Comment: @BenThul, we are fetching existing record from 1 , so we are trying some prefix. a1,b2,c2.when it enters 100's . We want to get a101,b102,..like that, should skip every 100 for this

Comment: That's... just saying the same thing in a different way. Why is it important that the hundreds get skipped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CTE and then some integer maths. This is pseudo SQL, due to the lack of sample data, however, this shold get you where you need:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT {Your Columns},
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (/*PARTITION BY {Column(s)} */ORDER BY {Columns}) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT {Your Columns},
       RN + ((RN-1) / 99) AS RN
FROM CTE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PhwKz0pa)

Comment: I'm curious why not go with Modulus `%` . Maybe i didn't understood him well ?

Comment: Because the OP isn't looking to filter the data, @AnelHodžić . That still want row 100, but they want it to be labeled as row 101.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, the solution works , is there any way to avoid CTE, and get the value 100,200 skipped with any case condition

Comment: To avoid the CTE you would need to instead use the expression for the column defined as `RN` in the `SELECT` (twice).

Comment: @Larnu , I checked this logic is going to 101 after 99,...for 99 ->101, 199->201, 299 ->302,399->403 and so on ..But I want 99->101, 199->201, 299->301

Comment: @abiramiramachandran that can't work. You have `100=101`, which means that `198=199` and `199 = 201`, but then when you get to `297` you'll then be using `299`; if `299` needs to be `301` what number should `298` be? It can't be `300`, as that's not a permissible value, and it can't be `299` as that's `297`.

Comment: @Larnu We just want to skip every 100.. and move to next number. Just sequence should be 99,101,102,103...199,201,202, 203..299,301,302,303,...399,401..We don't want to assign it for pervious values.

Comment: And the above does that, @abiramiramachandran ... So what's the problem?

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for your support. Just I'm checking for that logic